# How can I write queries for the Bluemix SQL database

Tags: db2, ibm-cloud

How can I create a table that includes auto increment and NOT NULL. I am using the sql database console that bluemix offers. 
The following query gives me an error.

```
CREATE TABLE discounts (
  id INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  title VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL,
  expired_date DATE NOT NULL,
  amount DECIMAL(10,2) NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (id)
);
```

The error is:

> DDL failed with message 
>   _ Exception. _ state = 42601; error code = -104; error Message = Error for batch element #1: An unexpected token "," was found following
>   "NULL AUTO_INCREMENT". Expected tokens may include: "".. _CODE=-104,
>   _STATE=42601, DRIVER=3.66.46

Answer (score 1, accepted):

DB2 does not support the "AUTO_INCREMENT" statement.

You can use the "GENERATED ALWAYS AS IDENTITY" command instead.

CREATE TABLE discounts ( id INT NOT NULL GENERATED ALWAYS AS IDENTITY (START WITH 1 INCREMENT BY 1), title VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL, expired_date DATE NOT NULL, amount DECIMAL(10,2) NULL, PRIMARY KEY (id) );

Further details about creating automatic values are detailed [here](http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/data/library/techarticle/0205pilaka/0205pilaka2.html)

Comment: It works, thanks a heap. I was following steps in this article. http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/library/wa-deployrest-app/index.html     Under step one there is also a query to insert. Is it possible to run an insert statement in the SQL database console?

Comment: Yes you should be able to.

Comment: This insert query doesn't seem to be working, do you have any idea why?           INSERT INTO products (id, name, price) VALUES
(1, Garden spade, 15.99),
(2, Cotton hammock, 54.50),
(3, Single airbed, 35.49);                      The error message is "An unexpected token "spade" was found following "E) VALUES (1, Garden". Expected tokens may include: "".. SQLCODE=-104, SQLSTATE=42601, DRIVER=3.66.46"

Comment: Add quotes around the product names?

Comment: I tried that too. The error is : "Garden spade" is not valid in the context where it is used.. SQLCODE=-206, SQLSTATE=42703, DRIVER=3.66.46

Comment: What's the schema for products?

Comment: It was something really simple like CREATE TABLE products
(
  id INT,
  name VARCHAR(5) 
  price decimal(5,2) 
);